# Tomcat Send "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" and "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy" Headers to Enable SharedArrayBuffer on JavaScript

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers, cross-domain, freebsd

I've built a React 17.0.2 application which has a dependency using "SharedArrayBuffer" (ffmpeg.wasm). This requires these Response Headers [as per the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer):

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

I am serving the React application via Tomcat 10. How do I modify the default web.xml to include those headers?

**Update 1:**

I've found some documentation that I think shows it is possible to send these headers, **I just do not know what to put in `web.xml` to make it happen.**

[This doc says that to enable CORS on Tomcat, you can use the filter tag.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) It also says, "This filter is an implementation of W3C's CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) specification". [The specification they reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html) includes both of those headers:

- [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#cross-origin-embedder-policy)
- [Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#cross-origin-opener-policies)

**Solution:**

Since there is no native way to send these response headers, I had to use [this code](https://github.com/nreese/StaticHeaders) to add them. I ran git clone, made sure I had CATALINA_HOME set, ran make.sh, moved the resulting .jar to the lib/ directory in Tomcat, and matched the permissions with with surrounding jars. I wrote two filters in my web.xml and restarted Tomcat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenerPolicyHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>StaticHeaders</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy</param-name>
        <param-value>same-origin</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenerPolicyHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>EmbedderPolicyHeaderFiler</filter-name>
    <filter-class>StaticHeaders</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy</param-name>
        <param-value>require-corp</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EmbedderPolicyHeaderFiler</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS filter only handles the `Access-Control-*` headers and does not do anything about `Cross-Origin-*` headers.

If you wish to set `Cross-Origin-*` headers, you will either have to manage that yourself, or submit a pull-request to the Tomcat project.

Comment: I think its strange that the implementation excludes those headers even though they are in the specification. I'll update with my solution. Do you have any insight as to why Tomcat does not follow the specification it claims to? Thanks.

Comment: Yes: the CORS filter was written at one point in history, and the specification was later expanded to include new headers. The implementation wasn't updated. And here we are.